# Drop frames when GStreamer pipeline is in GST_STATE_PAUSED state (uridecodebin3 element)

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I am using GStreamer uridecodebin3/source to decode RTSP stream, and sometimes I want to pause it (just to free my CPU cycles when stream is not visible in my app). Changing it's state to **GST_STATE_PAUSED** and again to **GST_STATE_PLAYING** after some amount of time causes rendering frames started from the time point when it was paused. I don't want that behaviour: I just want to render "current" frames. Can I configure it in such way?

I know I can just ignore the produced frames but it will not free my CPU from decoding it.

Comment: Why not set Pipeline State to stopped eg null and start pipeline later on

Comment: @Christoph because starting it again takes an amount of time (latency included) and app user will not see the output immediately.

Comment: OK then you need a Tee element with two pipelines one for displaying it and one for discarding with a fakesink. But when u Connect your decoding Pipeline you would also have short delay because of waiting next I frame depense on gop size when its h264 :)

Comment: @Christoph I already use fakesink (with handoff callback), but ignoring frames from it doesn't prevent the frames from being decoded (which is why my CPU is still hot).

Comment: U need tee element whit two branches one with Decoder and one without Decoder with fakesink